# LibGDX - How to clear the Screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to display 2 different screens, changing when the user touches the screen. So far with the code below the screens change but the text just keeps overlapping and piling up. I need to dispose of EVERYTHING on the screen before switching.

One of the 2 similar pages(only the text is different on the 2)

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;

public class MainMenu implements Screen {
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Screens game;
    BitmapFont font;

    public MainMenu(Screens game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        CharSequence str = "Main Menu";
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();

         batch.begin();
         font.draw(batch, str, 200, 200);
         batch.end();

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) // use your own criterion here
            game.setScreen(game.anotherScreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Screens.java

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class Screens extends Game {


    MainMenu mainMenuScreen;
    AnotherScreen anotherScreen;


   @Override
    public void create() {
            mainMenuScreen = new MainMenu(this);
            anotherScreen = new AnotherScreen(this);
            setScreen(mainMenuScreen);              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your render function to:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      //clears the buffer 

    CharSequence str = "Main Menu";
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont();

     batch.begin();
     font.draw(batch, str, 200, 200);
     batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) // use your own criterion here
        game.setScreen(game.anotherScreen);
}
```

Comment: oh wow, I knew that too. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll accept the answer when it lets me

Comment: @ ObieMD5 yup, Now I can make various pages for my application. Next task is to figure out how to utilize the back button.. But thats later